# How to manage deep router dynamic id pages to go back to previous one, in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, routes

I am trying to implement a routing for my react project. No problem for the react router dom, but I am wondering how manage deep routing page's id, in order to be able to go back to previous pages.

Until now I have implemented `useLocation` and also `useParams` but I could not figure it out the proper way.
In my case I have 3 level pages "Main Category --> Category --> Sub category ".
Each category has multiple sub categories, so ID has to be dynamic.

The problem is, when I am in "Sub category" and I go back, react does not know which "Category" i came from.

Should I pass the "category ID" until the sub category page?
It is better use `useLocation`, `useParams` or `Redux` ? Or maybe you have others better solutions...

```
`const location = useLocation();

  const catName = location.state?.name;
  const catID = location.state?.id;`

  <BackArrow to={`/catPage/${catID}`} title={catName}/>
```

Comment: What is the version of your react router?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^6.8.0"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back to the previous page in `react-router-dom v6` then you can use `useNavigate`.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const Component = () => {
   const navigate = useNavigatge()

   return (
      <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>Go back</button>
   )
}
```

You can also change the number inside `navigate` to -2 if you want to go back two pages and so on.

Comment: I don't think is the right solution, since i have dynamic id

Comment: Try it i think it'll work even with the dynamic id.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your routing structure is made out of nested routes, you could use a relative path using react-router-dom's `Link` ([Source](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.8.1/components/link)) like so:

```js
<Link to="../">Parent category</Link>

// OR in some cases

<Link to=".." relative="path">Parent category</Link>
```

Maybe take a look also at the `useNavigate` hook ([React-dom doc](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate))